# Android samples files for Azure B2C require configuration file information to be replicated in B2CConfiguration class as well

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I was implementing Azure AD B2C in Multiuser mode and was reading the [sample files](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java#b2cmodefragment-class). Why is there a configuration class which states:

"If you'd like to use your own app registration, you will also need to update B2CConfiguration.java to match with your configuration json file."

Doesn't that seem to defeat the purpose of having a configuration file? Shouldn't the values be accessible through the module somehow as long as the configuration file is

[This code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/azuresamples/msalandroidapp/B2CModeFragment.java) shows the calling of the [json configuration file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/res/raw/auth_config_b2c.json):

```
    // Creates a PublicClientApplication object with res/raw/auth_config_single_account.json
    PublicClientApplication.createMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication(getContext(),
            R.raw.auth_config_b2c,
            new IPublicClientApplication.IMultipleAccountApplicationCreatedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCreated(IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication application) {
                    b2cApp = application;
                    loadAccounts();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                    displayError(exception);
                    removeAccountButton.setEnabled(false);
                    runUserFlowButton.setEnabled(false);
                    acquireTokenSilentButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            });
```

And the [B2CConfiguraiton](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/azuresamples/msalandroidapp/B2CConfiguration.java) shows:

```
/**
 * Name of your B2C tenant hostname.
 */
final static String azureAdB2CHostName = "fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com";

/**
 * Name of your B2C tenant.
 */
final static String tenantName = "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com";

/**
 * Returns an authority for the given policy name.
 *
 * @param policyName name of a B2C policy.
 */
public static String getAuthorityFromPolicyName(final String policyName) {
    return "https://" + azureAdB2CHostName + "/tfp/" + tenantName + "/" + policyName + "/";
}

/**
 * Returns an array of scopes you wish to acquire as part of the returned token result.
 * These scopes must be added in your B2C application page.
 */
public static List<String> getScopes() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            "https://fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com/helloapi/demo.read");
}
```

All of these values are in the configuration file, except for scopes.

Is there another option here so I don't need to hard code configuration information?

Comment: The configuration details are need to be hard coded dont have another way to retrive/change values dynamically. In the B2CConfiguration.java file it was clearly mentioned in comments section as `The value in this class has to map with the json configuration file (auth_config_b2c.json).`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration details (like tenentid, policy name)can't be rendered dynamically.

In the `B2CConfiguration.java` file if you see the comments section it was mentioned as `The value in this class has to map with the json configuration file (auth_config_b2c.json)`.

Comment: Thanks, Ragavendra. I saw that they mentioned the information was replicated, but thought it was inefficient and was wondering why it had to be that way as any change to the configuration file actually requires a code change, complicating moving across environments (dev, test, prod). BTW are you in Joy's org?

Comment: @Icj: Thanks for the feedback and a providing the right concerns.